# Injective group homomorphism on $\frac{Spin(4k+2)\times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/2}$ or $\frac{Spin(4k+2)\times U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4}\to U(2^{2k})$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, spin-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\U{U}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$From Pierre Deligne's [Notes on spinors](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/deligne.pdf), we can see that there is an injective group homomorphism (embedding):
\begin{equation}
\Spin(2n) \to \SU(2^{n-1}) \label1\tag1
\end{equation}
thus the embedding $\Spin(2n) \subset \SU(2^{n-1})$ for some positive integer $n$. I think this seems to be true for $n \geq 5$ but may not be true for $n \leq 4$.

Thus, below let us focus on $n \geq 5$.

We know that when $n=2k$, the center $Z(\Spin(4k))=\mathbf{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbf{Z}/2$. When $n=2k+1$, the center $Z(\Spin(4k+2))=\mathbf{Z}/4$.

So it is natural to generalize \eqref{1} to have an injective group homomorphism (embedding),
$$
\frac{\Spin(4k+2)\times \U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4} \to \frac{\SU(2^{2k})\times \U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4}. \label{1'}\tag{1'}
$$
The right hand side is true as long as ${\mathbf{Z}/4}\subset Z(\SU(2^{2k}))={\mathbf{Z}/2^{2k}}$ in the subgroup of center.

### My question:

1. Do you agree with me that \eqref{1} and \eqref{1'} are correct for $n \geq 5$? where $4k+2 \geq 10$?
2. I believe that there is an injective group homomorphism (embedding),
   $$
   \frac{\Spin(4k+2)\times \U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4} \to \frac{\SU(2^{2k})\times \U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/2^{2k}}=\U(2^{2k}), \label2\tag2
   $$
   because the irreducible spinorial representation of $\Spin(4k+2)$ is $2^{2k}$ dimensional, which is the same as the standard fundamental representation of $\U(2^{2k})$.
   Do you also agree with me on \eqref{2}?
3. Is there an injective group homomorphism (embedding),
   $$
   \frac{\Spin(4k+2)\times \U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/2} \to \frac{\SU(2^{2k})\times \U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/2^{2k}}=\U(2^{2k}). \label3\tag3
   $$
   Here the $\mathbf{Z}/2$ in the denominator is a normal subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}/4$ in \eqref{2}. The \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} are related by
   $$
   \begin{array}{ccc}
   \frac{\Spin(4k+2)\times \U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/2}   &  & \\
       \downarrow      &\searrow &          \\
   \frac{\Spin(4k+2)\times \U(1)}{\mathbf{Z}/4}  & \longrightarrow & \U(2^{2k})
   \end{array}. \tag{4}
   $$

---

Note for some background: The above we concern the $\Spin(2n)=\Spin(2n;\mathbb{R})$ acting on the vector space with the real $\mathbb{R}$ field. It is sufficient to study complex representations $\rho: \Spin(2n; {\mathbb C})\to \SL(2^{n-1}, {\mathbb C})$ or $\SL(2^{n}, {\mathbb C})$ of complex Spin groups $\Spin(2n, {\mathbb C})$: The restriction of such a representation to the compact Spin subgroup $\Spin(2n)$ is automatically *unitarizable*, i.e. the image is contained in a conjugate of $\SU(N)$ for appropriate $N$.

A representation $\rho$ of $\Spin(2n, \mathbb C)$ is called spinoral if it does not descend to the orthogonal group $\SO(2n, {\mathbb C})$ (equivalently, $\rho$ is injective). There are also half-spin or semi-spin representations: They are also spinoral. This is related to the above choice of $\SL(2^{n-1}, {\mathbb C})$ for irreducible semi-spin representation, and the above choice of $\SL(2^{n}, {\mathbb C})$ for  reducible  spin representation.

Comment: Why is $\rho$ injective if and only if it does not descend to $\operatorname{SO}(2n, \mathbb C)$?  Do you mean to require only the central character of $\rho$ to be injective?

Comment: I am not sure why you emphasize "descend to SO(2,ℂ)". Here I focus on  to Spin(2)=Spin(2;ℝ). I put a Note p.s. on Spin(2,ℂ) just for the convenience of sufficient studying complex representations

Comment: I emphasise "descend to $\operatorname{SO}(2n, \mathbb C)$" because that's where you made the claim:  "[$\rho$] does not descend to the orthogonal group $\operatorname{SO}(2n, \mathbb C)$ (equivalently, $\rho$ is injective)".  But I would be equally sceptical of the real version of the claim; I would definitely believe it on the level of central characters, but it's not clear to me on the level of the entire representation.

Comment: YES, "A representation  of Spin(2,ℂ) is called spinoral if it does not descend to the orthogonal group SO(2,ℂ) " --> so here I meant that this injective group homomorphism is pinned down by the spinor or spinoral representation of Spin(2,ℂ), no the vector representation of SO(2,ℂ).

Answer (score 2):

You really should have a look at F. Reese Harvey's book *Spinors and Calibrations*, where all of your questions are answered.

For example, your 'inclusion' (1) is *not* correct for sufficiently large $n$.  In fact, here are the actual embeddings:

There is an embedding $\mathrm{Spin}(8n)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})\times\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})$, but this latter product does not embed into $\mathrm{SU}(2^{4n-1})$, nor does $\mathrm{Spin}(8n)$.  Each of the two projections into the $\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})$ factors is a double cover of its image, which is a maximal proper subgroup $\mathrm{SO}'(8n)\subset\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})$ that, for $n>1$, is not isomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}(8n)$.  Under the above embedding, the center of $\mathrm{Spin}(4n)$ goes to the subgroup of order $4$ consisting of the elements $(\epsilon_1 I,\epsilon_2 I)\in \mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})\times\mathrm{SO}(2^{4n-1})$ where $\epsilon_i^2 = 1$.
(The case $n=1$ is, of course, the famous triality isomorphism, $\mathrm{SO}'(8)\simeq \mathrm{SO}(8)$.)

There is an embedding $\mathrm{Spin}(8n{+}4)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})\times\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})\subset \mathrm{SU}(2^{4n+1})\times\mathrm{SU}(2^{4n+1})$, but, for $n>0$, the projections of $\mathrm{Spin}(8n{+}4)$ into either $\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$ factor is a double cover onto a maximal proper subgroup $\mathrm{SO}'(8n{+}4)\subset\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$ that is not isomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}(8n{+}4)$.  In particular, $\mathrm{Spin}(8n{+}4)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{SU}(2^{4n+1})$ is *never* an embedding.
Under the above embedding, the center of $\mathrm{Spin}(8n{+}4)$ goes to the subgroup of order $4$ consisting of the elements $(\epsilon_1 I,\epsilon_2 I)\in \mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})\times\mathrm{Sp}(2^{4n})$ where $\epsilon_i^2 = 1$.  (The case $n=0$ is, of course, different, because, in this case, the embedding $\mathrm{Spin}(4)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Sp}(1)\times \mathrm{Sp}(1)=\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is an isomorphism.)

Finally, for $n\ge 1$ there is an embedding $\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{SU}(2^{2n})$.  The image of this embedding is a maximal proper subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2^{2n})$, and, under this embedding, the center of $\mathrm{Spin}(4n{+}2)$ goes to the multiples of the identity by a power of $i\in\mathbb{C}$. (Of course, this fails for $n=0$.)

Comment: Thanks, but I also asked extra U(1) factor with appropriate mod structure. Could you illuminate on that too?

Comment: thanks for the refs "F. Reese Harvey's book Spinors and Calibrations" I will read (son)!

Comment: I also have this puzzle mathoverflow.net/q/402173/336737 whether you can shed light on it too?

Comment: Hi Robert and Marina, I like your post. I find this answer may be partly supporting but also partly contradicting with part of the answer given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3296484

Comment: "Finally, for ≥1 there is an embedding Spin(4+2)↪SU(2^{2})." I agree with this. I think you agree  $$((4+2)×(1))/4→(2^{2}).$$
But I also ask whether this is true $$((4+2)×(1))/2→(2^{2})?$$

Comment: @МаринаMarinaS: I don't really understand your question.  When $k\ge 1$, the intersection of the subgroups $\mathrm{Spin}(4k{+}2)$ and the central subgroup $\mathrm{U}(1)\subset\mathrm{U}(2^{2k})$ is the set of $\lambda I$ where $\lambda^4 = 1$, so the first embedding works.  However, I don't see how you can get the second map as an embedding. The $\mathrm{U}(1)$ subgroup in $\mathrm{U}(2^{2k})$ has to commute with the subgroup $\mathrm{Spin}(4k{+}2)$, which forces it to be central (i.e., multiples of the identity), and that subgroup intersects  $\mathrm{Spin}(4k{+}2)$ in a group of order $4$.

Comment: Thanks, I also am not sure whether the other map (mod 4) gives an embedding. The reason I asked that is due to eq (4) and the other question as an input  mathoverflow.net/q/402173/336737